# US zip code automatically add - for 9 digits

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

How can I automatically add a `-` after the 5 digits of a US zip code (using AngularJS) if more than 5 digits are typed into the field and save it as a 9 digit string (like `12345-6789`) to validate it?

index.html

```
<div class="field">
      Country: {{location.zipcode}}
</div>
```

index.controller.js

```
...
      $scope.validateZipCode = function(location.zipcode) {
        return (zipcode.length === 5 || (zipcode.length === 10 && zipcode[5] === '-'));
      }
...
```

The user are not adding the `-` on their own and I feel like having an automatically populated `-` would be good UX.

> Please don't recommend the use of any libraries or zipcode validation APIs. This is a legacy project that needs minimal additions.

Comment: `if more than 5 digits are typed into the field and save it as a 9 digit string` ?? can you explain what this means actually ? what if user enters `6` digits ?

Comment: @CodeManiac You know how when you put in your US number into some text fields, it automatically adds `()` around the first 3 numbers and `-` after the 3rd and 6th number? If it is not 5 digits or 9 digits, I will obviously throw an error.

Comment: is it possible to divide your input into two sections ? if yes then this is the easiest way to achieve what you're trying to achieve, if not then you can use regex

Comment: Why the date and css tags?

Answer (score 2):

There's not going to be an out of the box way of doing this, so you'll have to create a function to count the characters and insert your hyphen when needed.

here is a basic example of how you can go about it.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('zip');
document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  const val = e.target.value;
  if (val.length < 6) { input.value = e.target.value; }
  if (val.length > 5) {
    // There are better ways to do this part, but here's the basic idea
    input.value = input.value.replace('-', '');
    input.value = input.value.substring(0, 5) + '-' + input.value.substring(5, input.value.length);
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="zip" />
```

One thing to note is that you *can* use an out of the box way to validate your input requirements by using the [pattern attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#pattern)

Comment: Thanks, @mwilson! I tried using the `angular.element(document.getElementById('zip'))` for AngularJS but it is not rendering the changes (but I can see it in my console). Any ideas on how to do that?